# Bash Scripting Export Filename to Variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to set a variable to a string representing a file's location and when I try to set the variable I keep on getting a 'permission denied' error, because the bash script is trying to execute the file.

Here is the code I'm using

```
date= 07062011
archive_dir=~/Documents/ABC/Testing
aggregate_file= `echo ${archive_dir}"/"${date}"_Aggregated.txt"`
```

The error I am getting is the following:

./8000.2146701.sh: line 32: /home/me/Documents/ABC/Testing/20110706_Aggregated.txt: Permission denied

From what I understand using the backticks should allow me to take the output of the command and put it into a variable and it doesn't seem to be working. When I just do the echo statement by itself the output is the file path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct problem is the space following:

```
aggregate_file=
```

That is:

```
aggregate_file= `echo ${archive_dir}"/"${date}"_Aggregated.txt"`
```

would have worked by simply removing the space after the assignment operator:

```
aggregate_file=`echo ${archive_dir}"/"${date}"_Aggregated.txt"`
```

But really it should have just been:

```
aggregate_file="${archive_dir}/${date}_Aggregated.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved this issue. Blame in on a .NET developer fooling around with bash scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use backticks and echo, just `aggregate_file="${archive_dir}/${date}_Aggregated.txt"`. And no spaces, as another poster mentioned.